# ¿Cuál es la dirección de la máquina de destino para una conexión ssh?

Tags: ssh, ip

Siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-copy-a-docker-image-from-one-server-to-another-without-pushing-it-to-a-repository-first), quiero transferar un imagen Docker desde el mio PC Windows10 hasta un otro, Fedora, usando rsync.

Entonces tengo que generar las claves

En la máquina desde la que me voy a conectar, escribo:

```
  $ ssh-keygen -t dsa -f {máquina_de_destinacion}
```

Pero que es `máquina_de_destinacion` ? Pensé que fue el ip pero cual ip? Aqui esta el resultado del commando sobre la maquina de destinaction:

```
bash-5.1$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:79:cc:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:6e:e0:f0:32:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.127/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 85180sec preferred_lft 85180sec
    inet6 fe80::1f09:9547:de95:63ae/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6f:6b:f1:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-4efe10895cbb: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:1a:42:3b:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-4efe10895cbb
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Porque hay multiples ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO es que hayan multiples IP, es que tienes multiples redes, algunas físicas `en,wl` y otras virtuales como la `docker0`.

De forma simple se deben de entender de la siguiente forma:

- lo(Loop Back): es una red virtual que linux utiliza para comunicarse con consigo mismo como por ejemplo cuando te comunicas con el localhots.
- enp3s0: se desglosa `en` es Ethernet, `p3` se refiere a la conexión PCI bus 3 `s0` no lo tengo claro es como Slot 0 y define la ubication en el hardware, aparte te dice que no esta disponible `state DOWN`.
- wlp5s0: se desglosa `wl` es Wireless Network, `p5` se refiere a la conexión PCI bus 5 y te dice que la ip es `inet 192.168.1.127`.
- docker0: es una red virtual que docker crea para realizar un puente entre la red del host y la red interna de docker, por lo general sueles ser 172.17 or 172.18. y terminación .1.

> En conclusión se puede observer que ese equipo esta conecta por medio
> de una red inalámbrica y la ip para comunicarte es `192.168.1.127`.

Esta imagen aclara mejor como es la red de docker, en vuestro caso `eth0` seria `enp3s0 o wlp5s0` según quien tenga la conexión de salida a la red:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]